# AttributeError: module 'flask' has no attribute 'Flask'

Tags: python, flask

I'm following a tutorial to learn to use Flask. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 lts and python3. Everything is newly installed and fully updated. Here is the entirety of my code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is saved as hello.py and when I try to run it from the terminal using "python3 hello.py" I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/wyattsullivan/Documents/flask.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'flask' has no attribute 'Flask'
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you have a file named flask.py locally which is imported instead of the Flask module. You could rename it to something else and try.

Answer (score 7):

You have a file named `flask.py` in the same directory as your `hello.py`. That file overshadows the flask module since it is locally available. Hence in `hello.py`,

`from flask import Flask` is interpreted as from the `flask.py` file import Flask which doesn't exist in that file.

To fix, rename that `flask.py` to something else.